# Expose the Coordinate System Parameters in FME

Tags: coordinate-system, fields-attributes, fme-form

I would like to take fields in the Coordinate System Properties. (Data Inspector) to use as user attributes. [image: Coordinate System Parameters]

Answer (score 4):

In FME 2020 you can use the **[CoordinateSystemDescriptionConverter](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/coordinatesystemdescriptionconverter.htm)** to extract the information to an attribute.

Here is an example:

[image]

This is represented in different ways OGC WKT (Well-Known Text) used here - you can then split the attribute into separate fields using the attributesplitter using comma to separate the values.